# Save Photo with Exif tag(rotation) by Xamarin CommunityToolkit CameraView

Tags: xamarin, camera, exif

I am building a photo application for Android 9 using Xamarin5(Visual Studio 2019 Windows10).
I have a question about CameraView in XamarinCommunityToolkit.

I was able to take a photo using CaremaView.
I would like to know how to save this photo.
Currently, in this CaremaView, SavePhotoToFile is commented out.
https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/blob/main/src/CommunityToolkit/Xamarin.CommunityToolkit/Views/CameraView/ CameraView.shared.cs

So, I tried to save the file as follows

CameraViewPage.xaml.cs

```
void CameraView_MediaCaptured(object? sender, MediaCapturedEventArgs e)
{
    previewPicture.Rotation = e.Rotation; //90
    PreviewPicture.Source = e.Image;
    File.WriteAllBytes(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss" + ".jpg"), PhotoBytes);
}
```

The file is now saved.
However, the resulting jpg file does not have any rotation information. So, load it again and run

```
<Image Source="{Binding FileFullPath}" />.
```

the vertical photo will fall to the side.

How can I save the rotation information (e.Rotation) as an Exif tag (IFD0(0x0112) 90) in jpg?

Comment: Is PhotoBytes the data you rotated ?

Comment: Thank you comment.
How can I rotate PhotoBytes?

Comment: I think you should first determine the rotation of the image exif data and then adjust the rotation of the ImageView.In fact, your stored image should be rotated, so it will be rotated when displayed.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.
I think you need to determine the rotation of the exif data of the image and adjust the rotation of the ImageView.
You are correct.
In fact, the saved image is not rotated.
So when it is displayed, it is rolled over.

So it needs to be rotated.